# Servlet is unable to generate output on second time

Tags: java, servlets

Please review my code:

```
        package controller;

        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.Io Exception;
        import java.io.PrintWriter;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Iterator;
        import java.util.logging.Level;
        import java.util.logging.Logger;
        import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
        import javax.servlet.ServletException;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
        import model.dbLayer;
        import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
        import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
        import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
        import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
        import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

        /**
         *
         * @author sarir

    /*i am having jsp page with multipart enctype and saving image path in db


        i am able to insert a first record successfully.Everything goes wellBut when a click a hyperlink again to insert second record  and i`enter code here`nserting all the fields into the forma and submitting as posting a request to above servlet it does not produce output and neither any exceptions...any help would be appreciated..plz i am doing final year project...help me

    */
         */
        public class multipartServlet extends HttpServlet {
        //reading input from jsp page 
           String path="";
           Long CRN;
           String username="";
            private ArrayList<String>list=new ArrayList<String>();

//to process enctype dtat
            protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException, FileUploadException, Exception {
                response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

                username=request.getSession(true).getAttribute("uname").toString();
                try {            
                          CRN=generatorCRN.getCRN();
                          list.add(CRN.toString());
                          list.add(username); 

             FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
             ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
             Iterator<FileItem> iterator = upload.parseRequest(request).iterator();
             File uploadedFile;
             String dirPath="C:\\Users\\Bhatjaved\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\6thsem\\build\\web\\view\\Photo";

             while (iterator.hasNext()) {



                            FileItem item = iterator.next();
                            if (!item.isFormField()) {

                                String fileNameWithExt = item.getName();


                                File filePath = new File(dirPath);

                                if (!filePath.exists()) {
                                    filePath.mkdirs();
                                }

                            uploadedFile = new File(dirPath + "/"+CRN.toString().concat(".jpg"));

                               path=dirPath +filePath.separator+CRN.toString().concat(".jpg");
                                item.write(uploadedFile);  

                            }
                            else {
                    String otherFieldName = item.getFieldName();
                    String otherFieldValue = item.getString();
                            if(otherFieldValue.equals("Select"))
                                ;
                            else                        
                        list.add(otherFieldValue);
                            }
                       }





                    dbLayer dl=new dbLayer();
                    int res= dl.registerperson("missing_persons", list,path);
                    out.println(res);
                    if(res>0)
                    {
              //request.getRequestDispatcher("/view/missingsucess.jsp").forward(request, response); 
                       response.sendRedirect("/online_complaint/view/missingsucess.jsp?crn="+CRN);
                    }




                }catch(Exception ex)

                {

                 out.print(ex.getCause().toString());

                }


                finally {    

                    out.close();
                }
            }

            // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
            /**
             * Handles the HTTP
             * <code>GET</code> method.
             *
             * @param request servlet request
             * @param response servlet response
             * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
             * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
             */
            @Override
            protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
                try {
                    processRequest(request, response);
                } catch (FileUploadException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(multipartServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(multipartServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

            /**
             * Handles the HTTP
             * <code>POST</code> method.
             *
             * @param request servlet request
             * @param response servlet response
             * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
             * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
             */
            @Override
            protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
                try {
                    processRequest(request, response);
                } catch (FileUploadException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(multipartServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(multipartServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }


            </editor-fold>
        }
```

Comment: What ? When ? Where ?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your post what you are *unable to generate* the second time around, but one obvious problem is `list`.

You're failing to empty this list each time, and judging by the name of the method you pass it to (`registerperson`), it's likely that you are giving it an over-populated object.

Perhaps this should be local to your method as it doesn't see to have a need to be an instance variable.